# Numpy: getting clusters from a 2d array black/white image mask

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with dimensions (512, 512, 3), which represents an RGB image. The image is a simple black and white mask, visualisation:

[image]

My goal is to identify the x largest clusters of white pixels in this mask and produce new images exclusive to each cluster. For example, for the image above, if x = 2, my desired algorithm would produce the following 2 images:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way I can do this simply with numpy? My naive approach has been to use depth-first-search.

Comment: you need to run the algorithm to find the regions. the basic idea is as follow, you have the set of the white points then pick any and run dfs on each to find all the connected points and remove from your set. continue this to find all the regions. for each regions as well you can define area as number of pixels. and finally build the images that you want with biggest regions. algorithms like this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-islands/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find your points like this:

```
im = Image.open('Nkuf9.png')
data = np.array(im)[:,:,0]
wpoint = np.where(data == 255)
points = set((x, y) for x, y in zip(*wpoint) )
```

and a simple dfs to find each connected region, you could put all in a class.

```
def generate_neighbours(point):
    neighbours = [
        (1, -1), (1, 0),(1, 1),
        (0, -1), (0, 1),
        (1, -1), (1, 0),(-1, 1)
    ]
    for neigh in neighbours:
        yield tuple(map(sum, zip(point, neigh)))


def find_regions(p , points):
    reg = []
    seen = set()
    def dfs(point):
        if point not in seen:
            seen.add(point)
            if point in points:
                reg.append(point)
                points.remove(point)
                for n in generate_neighbours(point):
                    dfs(n)
    dfs(p)
    return reg

region =[]

while points:
    cur = next(iter(points))
    reg = find_regions(cur, points)
    region.append(reg.copy())



areas = {idx: area for idx, area in enumerate(map(len,region))}
areas = sorted(areas.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)


num = 2
for idx, area in enumerate(areas[:num]):
    plt.subplot(1,num, idx + 1)
    im = np.zeros((512, 512))
    for x,y in region[area[0]]:
        im[x,y] = 255
    plt.imshow(im)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! When I run it I am getting an error from the line: areas = {idx: area for idx, area in enumerate(map(len,region))}. The error is: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: @Ben123 I did updated a bit to be cleaner, region is list, where is the np array ? maybe you have defined variable with same name? more specifically maybe you have defined a variable called "len" ?

Comment: Yes! You were right there was some issue related to another previously defined variable. Thanks very much.